# Passing string with single quote via onclick to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, escaping

I have this button with an onclick attribute which calls a function named `appr`. The parameters passed to `appr` are different for each button, generated by PHP:

```
return "<button type='button' onclick='appr(".$id.",\"".$qr['name']."\");'>Approve</button>";
```

Which results in this HTML:

```
<button type='button' onclick='appr(3,"Dave O'Shea");'>Approve</button>
```

The Javascript function look like this.

```
function appr(id,name){
  // some code here...
  alert(name);
}
```

The code works fine, except for strings with single quotes, which fails. Any ideas why?

Comment: Because single quotes are used as the delimiter around the attribute value.  So the inner single quote terminates the attribute value too early

Comment: try replacing `'` with `\'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, single quotes denote the attribute boundaries:

```
onclick='appr(
        ^
```

so the first `'` that comes afterwards will finish the attribute value.

You can fix it by replacing the `'`s with HTML entities that result in quote marks instead, so that the generated HTML comes out to

```
<button type='button' onclick='appr(3,"Dave O&quot;Shea");'>Approve</button>
```

```html
<button onclick='alert(&quot;foo&quot)'>Test</button>
```

But it would be far better to avoid inline handlers entirely and add the listeners with Javascript instead. For example, for each button, push an object containing the associated `id` and `name` to an array, and include that array in the response to the client somehow - for example, by putting the JSON into a script tag and selecting / parsing that script tag content. Then iterate over the array and add a listener to each button. Something like:

```
// retrieve array however you want
const arr = [
  { id: 3, name: "Dave O'Shea" },
  // more objects
];
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (const [i, { id, name }] of arr.entries()) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    appr(id, name);
  });
}
```

Or anything else along those lines. Just avoid putting handlers in the HTML markup as element attributes.

Comment: The values on the appr() function are dynamic from PHP variables.

Comment: Indeed, and to tie those values to the buttons, you should figure out a way to do it *other* than using inline handlers, if at all possible (since they have escaping problems, as you're running into, because they require global pollution,  because they have very weird `with` behavior, and because they're just bad practice in general). Better to create an array of objects in PHP and send that array to the client, or use data attributes, or *anything* other than inline handlers.

Comment: Thanks, I used your suggestion to use data attributes instead. I came up with `return '<button type="button" data-id="'.$id.'" data-info="'.addslashes($qr['name']).'">Approve</button>';` which now work. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use template literals and escape function for dynamic data in attributes. Like following example

```
let str = escape("Dave O'Shea")
return `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunc(str)"></a>`
```

then in function unescape the string

```
function myFunc(str){
  str = unescape(str)
}
```